# PHP illegal string offset error

Tags: php

I have this code I don't know why I get error from it.

```
if( ! in_array($repeatType, ['monthly', 'weekly', 'daily'])){
    // do somehting
}
$monthly = ['two_years' => 26, 'offset_const' => 4, 'add_unite' => 'weeks'];
$weekly = ['two_years' => 52*2, 'offset_const' => 1, 'add_unite' => 'weeks'];
$daily = array('two_years' => 365*2, 'offset_const' => 1, 'add_unite' => 'days');

for ($i=0; $i < $$repeatType['two_years']; $i++) { #<--- here I get the error

    // ..... // rest of the code
```

This is so weird cause I have checked `var_dump($$repeatType)` output, it seems fine:

```
array(3){["two_years"]=>int(730)["offset_const"]=>int(1)["add_unite"]=>string(4)"days"}
```

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty it's fine to have double `$$`, since it makes variable `$monthly`, `$weekly` or `$daily` to be dynamicaly selected

Comment: Did you try `($$repeatType)["two_years"]`?

Comment: ^ I guess he is missing the `count`

Comment: @GuyT nope, `$foo["two_years"]` is a number, no `count()` missing.

Comment: @Maerlyn it caused syntax error `syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ';'`.

Comment: @Mohammed, could you tell us the precise error text? Thx

Comment: @peter_the_oak It's `Illegal string offset 'two_years'`

Comment: You are making incorrect variables? Your `$$repeatType['two_years']` will produce variable `$730` that is not valid name for variable AND there is no variable with name `$730`

Comment: @Justinas don't think so, you can re-read `var_dump($$repatType)` output above, and check Maerlyn answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a syntax limitation. PHP is trying to bind the array-index operator to $repeatType (which is a string) and an associative key is invalid in a string, thus causing your problem.

You need to explicitly specify where your variable starts and begins like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i < ${$repeatType}['two_years']; $i++) {}
```

A workaround is to assign it to a temporary variable like this:

```
$selectedRepeatType = $$repeatType;
for ($i=0; $i < $selectedRepeatType['two_years']; $i++) {}
```

Comment: Thanks ... never heard about that before.

Comment: Note that there is not really a need for a workaround. The curly brackets as you mentioned work just fine.

Comment: @peter_the_oak I have tried curly brackets but I got a syntax error after using them.

Comment: I tried them too :-) Like this: 1. `$name = "two_years";` 2. `$two_years = array('A' => 10, 'B' => 20);` 3. `print_r(${$name}['A']);` On my side, these lines work like a charm.

Comment: @peter_the_oak oh.. sorry you're right !!, I have tried normal brackets before which is mentioned in the comments above but curly brackets works!!

Comment: @peter_the_oak yes, it is not really neccessary to make it work, but the brace symbol is quite unknown among the PHP developers I'm familiar with, so the workaround is less likely to cause a WTF moment.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand what you want ,but this expression $$repeatType['two_years'] is ambiguous , at least for me it takes me some time to run the code to find out what the output,so first of all I should suggest you don't use such a expression.

OK,come back to the question,you expected `$$repeatType['two_years']` to return one of the number 26,52*2,and 365*2.But let us run the code.

```
$name='a';
$a=array('n'=>1);
$a=array('n'=>2);
$a=array('n'=>3);

var_dump($$name['n']);  //array(1) { ["n"]=> int(3) }
var_dump($$name);       //array(1) { ["n"]=> int(3) }
var_dump(${$name}['n']);//int(3)
```

OK ,we know what happend, and you can find why [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Answer (score 0):

From your code, i can understand that you haven't set a value for $repeatType['two_years']. First assign a value

```
$repeatType['two_years'] = "monthly";
```

Now "$monthly" is an array so you call:

```
for ($i=0; $i < ${$repeatType['two_years']}['two_years']; $i ++){
    //Loop 26 times.
}
```

$repeatType['two_years'] need to be defined or it will give a PHP error.

Comment: if you check my code again, you can realize that the first line of it checks for `$reapeatType` value, it's already assigned, the problem was I didn't add the curly brackets, thanks for your suggestion.